# C#: Attach a custom file (.sl) to an email

Tags: c#, .net, email, batch-file

I am trying to attach a custom file to an email with no avail. The below code calls a batch file which creates an encrypted file and then i try to attach that file to an email. The batch file creates the file successfully but when it tries to attach it says that the file does  not exist. I read that you need to create a memory buffer or attach to same thread, i tried thinkering with it but i am really stumped right now. Can anyone assist?

Code:

```
                string file = @"C:\EncryptedFile\file.sl";

                //EXECUTE BATCHFILE SUPPLYING PARAMETERS TO IT
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
                                            file,
                                            key,
                                            doc1, 
                                            doc2);
                process.StartInfo.FileName = MyBatchFile;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();

                //attach to email
                Attachment attachment;
                attachment = new Attachment(file);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path 'C:\EncryptedFile\file.sl'.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at
>   System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName,
>   String mediaType)    at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase..ctor(String
>   fileName)    at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)

Thanks!

Comment: have you checked by putting debug point (halting the batch file execution) that file is already exists when attachment code is getting called? 
also, I would suggest to create two batch files. one is to create the file and the other is to attach it into the mail. you can call second batch file in the end of the first batch file's execution having some wait until file is not getting created properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear. It means that the file did not exist at the moment the attachment was created.
I would modify your code:

1. Wait util process exit. Without it you create an attachment before the batch file creates it.
2. Check for exit code (if your batch supports it)
3. Check for file before create attachment to handle the situation when batch did not create a file for some reason.

Comment: Hey thanks man, number 1 was easier to implement and it worked. All i needed was to place a process.WaitForExit(); before adding the attachment and it worked! I would mark your comment as an answer but i don't have enough rep.

Comment: Do you know how to do a "wait" for the mail send() to finish then move on? I am trying to delete the encrypted file after the mail is sent but i am getting a "File is in use" error (Obviously i'm trying to delete the file while the mail is using it so i'll need to put a wait or something).

Comment: Sorry for late response, did not see notification. I believe the method 'send' is executed synchronously. But you should dispose Attachment object as well as MailMessage. I am pretty sure that attachment object blocks the file.